# Changing the class of an exception after raising it

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, cpython

I wrote the following code, which raises an exception, while a thread continuously changes the class of the raised exception:

```
import threading
import time

class Foo(Exception):
    pass

class Bar(Exception):
    pass

class MyExc(Exception):
    pass

b = True
e = MyExc()
def mess():
    global e
    global b
    time.sleep(0.00000000000000000000001)
    while b:
        e.__class__ = Bar
        e.__class__ = Foo
threading.Thread(target=mess).start()

try:
    try:
        try:
            try:
                try:
                    raise e
                except Foo:
                    print(1)
            except Foo:
                print(2)
        except Foo:
            print(3)
    except Foo:
        print(4)
except Foo:
    print(5)
except Bar:
    print('bar')
except MyExc:
    print('myexc')

b = False
```

With CPython, different timings make it print either `1`, `bar`, or `myexc` (you may have to tweak the sleep time a bit to get either three of them). But never an other number.

Why? Is it because CPython does not run other threads while unwinding the stack?

Comment: I can't see why it would ever print any number apart from 1. If the exception is Foo, 1 will be printed; why would any of those other `except` blocks be triggered?

Comment: Because initially, the exception is not an instance of Foo. But then, I expected the thread to make it an instance of Foo while Python unwinds the stack, triggering one of the middle except statements

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is happening is that when you start your thread, it is changing the type of 'e' before it gets to the raise command. Once it gets to the raise command, the exception is captured at it's current type, which will either be MyExc, Foo, or Bar, and then moves through the exception handling logic.

If you want to play with it more, you can reraise the exception inside the try/except logic. Something like:

```
try:
    try:
        try:
            raise e
        except:
            print(1)
            raise
    except:
        print(2)
        raise
 except:
     print(3)
     raise
```

Comment: Now it prints `myexc`, `bar`, or all numbers. Never a subset of the numbers.

Comment: Right. I think once the exception is initially raised, the internals of CPython is creating a new instance of the exception and passing that through the exception handling logic. This way you can't change an exception's class or message or anything while it is going through.

You can look through the exception handling logic here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/errors.c